# Как сдвинуть все элементы массива влево на 2?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, visual-studio-2017

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void sdvig(int * m, int size, int sdv) {
    int max = *m;
    bool s = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (m[i] > max)
            max = m[i];
    }

        for (int * p = m; *p <= size; p++) {
                *p = (p - m) + (sdv + 1);
        } 
        int num = 0;
        while (!s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (m[i] <= max) num++;
                else s = 1;
            }
        }
        for (int * p = m + num; *p <= size; p++) {
            *p = (p - (m + num)) - 5;
        }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) cout << m[j] << endl;
    cout << "      " << num << endl;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int m[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    sdvig(m, 5, 2);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

У меня такая проблема: мне нужно сдвинуть все элементы массива влево на 2. То есть если начальный массив {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, то должно получиться {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}. В чем моя ошибка? Исправьте, если не трудно.

Comment: С какой целью в задаче циклического сдвига делается поиск максимального элемента массива???

Comment: У меня был такой алгоритм: 1) Найти макс элемент начального массива. 2) Найти сколько элементов до макс элемента включительно начального массива. (num) 3) Сдвинуть все элементы начального массива на 2, тем самым получить второй массив. 4) Заменить все элементы после num на начальные.

Answer (score 3):

Чтоб обойтись без всяких временных массивов, проще всего развернуть массив - сначала весь, а потом две части:

```
void reverse(int * a, int begin, int end)
{
    for(int i = begin, j = end; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
}

void rotate(int * a, int size, int count)
{
    reverse(a,0,size-1);
    reverse(a,0,count-1);
    reverse(a,count,size-1);
}
```

Это, конечно, если религия (или преподаватель) категорически запрещают использовать стандартную функцию [`rotate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)...

Answer (score 0):

Для сдвига массива лучше использовать [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) и [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/).

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void shift_left(int *arr, int size, int offset) {
    // массив для хранения элементов, которые перенесутся в конец
    int *tmp = new int[offset];

    // копируем во временный массив элементы, которые перенесутся в конец
    std::memcpy(tmp, arr, offset * sizeof(int));

    // сдвигаем элементы, начиная с arr[offset], на offset влево
    std::memmove(arr, &arr[offset], (size - offset) * sizeof(int));

    // копируем элементы из временного массива в конец исходного
    std::memcpy(&arr[size - offset], tmp, offset * sizeof(int));

    delete[] tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    shift_left(m, 5, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << m[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```