# Рекурсивный циклический сдвиг массива на 5 элементов вправо c++

Tags: c++, рекурсия, динамические-массивы

1. Создать динамический одномерный массив
2. реализовать рекурсивный циклический сдвиг массива на 5 по кругу [1,5,3,6,7,8,7,8,3,2...] -> [8,7,8,3,2,1,5,3,6,7]

Важно: размер массива задаётся с консоли

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
 
void shiftrec(int* arr, int size, int n){ /* наработки рекурсивного сдвига*/
  int tmp,i;
    if (c==0) return;
    
    tmp=arr[0];
    i=0;
    
    while(i<n-1)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        i++;
    }
 
    arr[n-1]=tmp;
    
    shiftrec(arr,n,c-1);
}
 
void shift(int*arr,int size){ /*циклический сдвиг без рекурсии*/
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
     int tmp = arr[0];
   for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
    {
       arr[j] = arr[j+1];
       arr[j+1] = tmp;
    }
  }
  
}
 
 
int main() {
  int size; // размер массива
  cout << "Enter size:";
  cin >> size;
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  int* arr = new int[size];
 
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = rand() % 10;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << arr[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
  shiftrec(arr,size, 5);
  //shift(arr,size);
  
 
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << arr[i] << " ";
 
  delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то задание, мягко говоря, неразумное. Потому что см. вот [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1094178/195342). Или [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/951474/195342). Чудят эти преподы, ох и чудят...

Answer (score 3):

Реализуйте циклический сдвиг на `1`

В функцию добавьте аргумент - целое число `shift` , насколько сдвигать.

Если `shift == 0` - сразу return

Выполнили сдвиг на 1 - вызываем функцию с `shift - 1`

В общем-то, у вас это уже есть, только неаккуратно сделано, с переменными катавасия